# Using FIRDatabaseReference more efficiently

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a difference in performance between those two codes?
The first one declares a database reference and uses it for every read and write.
The second one declares a database reference for every read and write.

Code 1:

```
let databaseReference = Database.database().reference()
databaseReference.setValue()
databaseReference.setValue()
databaseReference.setValue()
...
```

Code 2:

```
Database.database().reference().setValue()
Database.database().reference().setValue()
Database.database().reference().setValue()
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting a reference to a database location is a purely local operation, that is quite heavily optimized.

There is no significant performance difference between those two. Any performance difference there is will be overshadowed by any network call you do (like when you call `setValue()`.

When you wonder things like this, I recommend measuring it yourself btw. While I can reassure you all I want, nothing beats running a quick test and seeing the difference yourself, and in many cases it's not nearly as complex as you main initially think.